# Custom Confirmation tpl file

Tags: webforms

I would like to add a custom webform confirmation page that displays form submissions and then subsequent conditional markup.

**Background**
Ten question webform (assessment). User answers the questions. I'd like the confirmation page to display (on a per question/answer basis) a certain snippet of text.

Example below.
Question 1: If user answers XX, display certain snippet text OR if user answers A, display a different snipper of text.

Question 2: If user answers XX, display certain snippet text OR if user answers A, display a different snipper of text.

I've researched Webform Conditional Confirmation Messages module, but you it seems like you can only do a conditional confirmation based on a collection of answers and not individual answer values.

I was thinking of writing a php page that would pull all of the necessary fields and values and then redirecting the user, but that seems like overkill.

Thoughts? Any modules out there that can this?